# Amazon SES for multiple domains in same server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I've successfully implemented email sending through *Amazon SES* in my main domain. I now wanted to implement it for [quite] a few other domains we have for clients in the same server. Think of them as something like *WP* instances with individual domains, all in the same server as maindomain. They would send from an email address which works perfectly in maindomain, and is of course `@maindomain.com`

I tried sending an email from inside exampledomain.com through the `@maindomain.com` address and it throws `Illegal address error`. 
Will I have to verify each of these domains individually for this to work? I'm actually waiting for the verification of one of these to try, and it's not coming through. This I actually don't even know if it should work, I have the site in cloudflare and I'm not sure where to add these DNS in cloudflare. The main domain was easy because it's the one that appears in CF, these dynamic domains don't appear, but are affected.

Comment: "They would send from an email address which works perfectly in maindomain, and is of course @maindomain.com" so in other words you just have a single server sending all emails from a single domain "maindomain.com"?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to verify each domain individually. You have to set up a TXT record for each domain you want to use very that domain in AWS SES and then you can send emails.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping to avoid this. Specially because I have cloudflare in the server, and not set up individually for each domain. I have no idea where I sould put that DNS info in Cloudflare.

Comment: Your statement "cloudflare in the server, and not set up individually for each domain" doesn't make any sense at all. Perhaps you should describe your actual situation in detail. Are you talking about multiple root domains or multiple subdomains?

Comment: It's kind of a WP instances setup. They're not subdomains, they're all resolved internally in the server. We have them all pointed at our linode account, there they have individual DNS settings. Cloudflare is setup for the main domain, the thing is it affects these domains too, but they're don't have individual cloudflare settings.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it actually works without further messing with DNS settings. The error I was having was something else. I am now sending from not-my-main-domain-nor-subdomain.com from email@maindomain.com, only having properly verified maindomain.com in amazon console. Those settings yes I had to put in linode and cloudflare.